# Constant heavy led activity but no reported issues

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid1, ibm

On an IBM x3550 with two disks in hardware raid 1, have I heavy led activity on both drives, as soon as the raid controller is initialised at boot. It have been like this for more than a month, and the server doesn't do anything. It is a hit spare for a name server.

The raid controller doesn't report any issues.

**Question**

Have anyone an idea how I can debug this further and find the faulty disk or hardware?

Comment: I don't know anything about IBM servers, but is this RAID scrubbing? Check your controller settings to see what the scrub settings are.

Comment: Why are you viewing "constant LED activity" as a problem to be solved?

Comment: @longneck There are no scrub settings in the controller. But the activity does look a lot like scrubbing.